# Sum up the points from several multiple ring buffer in ArcGIS 10.6?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.6

I'm researching about nearest area from several area. So I used "multiple ring buffer" to know about distance from the areas.

Problem is I don't know how to sum up from these buffers.
I got different points from distance. (like in 250m : 3point, in 500m : 2point). I want to know how to sum up and become one shapefile.

Comment: I Think it would be easier to use [Generete](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/generate-near-table.htm) Near Table, Field Calculator to "round" values to 250,500,etc. and then Summary Statistics

Answer (score 1):

Use the spatial join tool. You would join the points to your rings. The trick here is it edit the merge rule to SUM in your field mapping. This does assume that the field you want to sum up for each ring is numeric!

This would create a new buffer dataset where summed points are attributes with the Buffer.